# Spacy: Creating empty or error Token instance?

Tags: python, token, spacy

I'm collecting some of the tokens in a Dict for further use.
The problem is that I need one token to play the role of None/NIL in case I don't find what I need in the doc to act as the no-value case i.e. still have all the attributes (the string value could be say some special char) ... i.e. act like Token, but not be a token from the doc.

Is there a way to create such Token ? Or may be copy some but modify .dep_, .pos_ etc.

Comment: Searching for same thing here. I'm recurring to using a bizarre token (like 'XXX&&&XXXˆ) that I don't expect to find in a real text. I would create a rule to not showing/printing it when needed to print it. In some cases, when I don't need the features and want the display to be straightforward,  I will have a list of tokens interpersed with str elems, mainly an empty string "", that would make that function. Still I'd like to have a sort of None/empty token. Did you/someone find a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to create a doc containing just one character (e.g. a space or * or any other character of your choice), i.e. nlp('<special character>'), and take the token at index 0. For example, if your special character is a #, this would look like:

```
empty_token = nlp('#')[0]
```

`empty_token` is a normal token, so it has all the attributes. Running the code below produces the corresponding output:

```
print('text:', empty_token.text)
print('pos:', empty_token.pos_)
print('dep:', empty_token.dep_)
```

Output:

```
text: #
pos: SYM
dep: ROOT
```